# A functor to find the minimum object that satisfies a condition

Tags: c++, functor

Suppose we’ve got an `std::vector<Obj>` where

```
struct Obj {
    int size;
    bool valid;
}
```

How can I write a functor to use with `std::min_element()` to find the smallest *valid* `Obj`.

Comment: invalid obj will be larger than all valid objs

Comment: What should happen if none are valid?

Comment: Undefined. It will never be called with no valid objects.

Answer (score 0):

I think that this works, but I might not be testing well enough...

```
auto ObjComp = [](Obj &a, Obj &b) {
    return !b.valid || (a.valid && a.size < b.size);
};
```

Comment: Don't you need to check if both a and b are valid?

Comment: In some way, I suppose you’re right.  This iteration is failing the test `vector<Obj> v = { {2, false}, {8, true}, {1, false}, {10, false} };` (it returns 2)

Comment: For min, you need to make sure invalid objects always compare higher.

Comment: Yep, it's close!  This should handle it all correctly: `return a.valid && (!b.valid || a.size < b.size);`

Comment: Ah… you posted while I was typing my edit.  Are they logically equivalent, or did I screw up again?

Comment: This comparator is wrong because it fails to satisfy `Compare` [requirements](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/Compare), namely `ObjComp(a, a)` should be always `false`. But `ObjComp(a, a) = !a.valid;`.

Answer (score 0):

You could do a [`std::partition`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/partition) before finding the `std::min_element`.

```
auto validity = [](const Obj& x) {
    return x.valid;
};
auto by_size = [](const Obj& lhs, const Obj& rhs) {
    return lhs.size < rhs.size;
};
auto pivot = std::partition(v.begin(), v.end(), validity);
auto valid_minimum = std::min_element(v.begin(), pivot, by_size);
if (valid_minimum == pivot) {
    std::cout << "No *active* minimum found!\n";
}
```

There's also [`std::stable_partition`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/stable_partition) if the ordering in the container matters somehow.

Comment: This is a very clever solution! But it will modify the container.

Comment: This functor will be called O(n!) times, and the vector must remain ordered. I would love to do it in a single linear search.

Comment: How will the "activeness" of each object change?  You could partition it in such a way you'll only ever have to do it once, before the calls ever start.  Also, O(n!) will be slow no matter _what_ your functor does, so you should be looking to change _that_ instead.

Comment: The problem’s NP-hard, so even with pruning the decision tree…

Comment: Maybe you should change your data structure?  O(n!) may mean that you could use [`std::next_permutation`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/next_permutation) to walk through things more efficiently, although I have no clue what problem you're solving.